# grep command usage in groovy

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, groovy

How to write the below shell in groovy

```
process_name = spin_user

if grep -i ${process_name} /tmp/output.log ; then 
  echo "Success" 
  grep -i ${process_name} output.log > final_output.log 
else 
  echo "failure" 
fi
```

Comment: i would say it's impossible (or extremely difficult). but you could do if-then-else on level of groovy without shell...

Comment: Do you know how to execute grep commands within if conditional loop in groovy?                         process_name = spin_user


if grep -i ${process_name} /tmp/output.log ;
                 then
                    echo "Success"
                    grep -i ${process_name} output.log > final_output.log
else
   echo "failure"
fi

Answer (score 1):

<< edited in response to comment >>

**1. Pure Groovy Solution**

If you just want to implement the functionality in your bash script in groovy, you can do something like this:

```
def processName = 'spin_user'
def outLog      = new File('/tmp/output.log')
def finalLog    = new File('final_output.log')

def lines       = outLog.readLines()
def hasProcess  = { it.toLowerCase().contains(processName) }

if(lines.any(hasProcess)) { 
  println "Sucess"
  finalLog.text = lines.findAll(hasProcess).join('\n')
} else { 
  println "failure"
}
```

should be noted that if your log file is large, there are better ways of searching for a string that do not require you to load the entire file into memory.

**2. Process Management Solution**

If you were specifically looking to use the linux system `grep` command from within groovy, the above will naturally not help you. The following groovy code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*

def processName = 'spin_user'
def outLog      = '/tmp/output.log'
def finalLog    = 'final_output.log'

def result = exec('grep', '-i', processName, outLog)
if (result) {
  println "success"
  new File(finalLog).text = result
} else { 
  println "failure"
}

String exec(String... args) {
  def out = new StringBuffer()
  def err = new StringBuffer()

  def process = args.toList().execute()

  process.consumeProcessOutput(out, err)
  process.waitForOrKill(5000)

  if (err) {
    println "ERROR:  executing ${args} returned ${process.exitValue()}"
    println "STDERR: ${err}"
  }

  out
}
```

will execute the `grep` command and should get you closer to what you want.

It should be noted that the output redirection `>` in your shell command is as far as I know hard to do on an external process from java/groovy and we are therefore writing the output to the `final_output.log` file from within groovy instead of executing the command using output redirection.

I also added a five second max timeout on the `grep` process execution. This is not required and that line can safely be removed, it's just there as a safeguard for cases where the grep blocks indefinitely.

Comment: Answer updated with alternative code that calls `grep`